# Overlap website with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, iframe, bho

I'm developing a BHO to deny access in prohibited websites. So when I find a certain URL, I just open an iframe with the code below:

```
Document:= IE.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
iFrame:= Document.createElement('iframe');
iFrame.setAttribute('src', 'denied.html', 0);
iFrame.setAttribute('position', 'fixed', 0);
iFrame.style.width:= '100%';
iFrame.style.left:= '0px';
iFrame.style.top:= '0px';
iFrame.style.border:= '0px';
iFrame.style.height:= '100%';
(Document.body as IHTMLDomNode).appendChild(iFrame as IHTMLDomNode);
```

but this code just opens the iframe into a little space at the end of the website. How to overlap the entire website with the content of my iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the position  to [absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

Comment: then user uses his anti-advertisement tool or just presses F12 and removes that frame altogether. If the site is prohibited - its content should be deleted, not masked.

Comment: I just answered the question. not trying to suggest a new way. Of course that using this method does not block the webpage. but for children lets say its good enough... if full restriction is needed, he should use a proxy and send a custom message when user tries to access some URL

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still getting the iframe in the end of the site and not overlaping it.

Comment: OK, what browser and OS do you use?

Comment: Works for me, maybe on the page there are elements above the `<body>`?

Comment: I'm clearing the entire webpage with:
`Document.body.innerHTML:= '';`
and them injecting the iframe with:
`iFrame:= Document.createElement('iframe');
iFrame.setAttribute('src', 'denied.html', 0);
iFrame.setAttribute('position', 'absolut', 0);
iFrame.style.width:= '100%';
iFrame.style.height:= '100%';
iFrame.style.left:= '100%';
iFrame.style.top:= '100%';
iFrame.style.border:= '0px';`
but now the iframe is on top of the page

Comment: it's like this: [link](http://s10.postimage.org/5tpl0ewzt/screenshot.jpg)
all the webpage being loaded into a small frame... the width is 100% but the height is like 10%...

Comment: Because the height is relative to the parent node, make sure the parent node is also 100% (the `<html>`?)

Comment: Look, I think the best solution is not using an iframe. I can cancel the navigation on the event BeforeNavigate2, then call a procedure to load the body src from another html... Something like Document.body.innerhtml = 'denied.html' ... you know how to do this?

Comment: That probably is a better solution to your project, Hwtrap, but you'll get better results if you ask that question separately instead of buried inside the comments to an answer of a different question. *This* question is about how to make iframes appear, not how to block access to Web sites.

Answer (score 3):

If you want absolutely block - you should not ADD element, you should REPLACE it.

So you have to make full-blown HTML page.
Then you probably can redirect browser to it, changing Document.Location property.
Or replace older content with new one doing Document.OuterHTML := .... your string.

The rule of thumb is simple - not append by replace, one way or another.

PS: why IE-only BHO that can easily be disabled in browser options ? I'd better ban prohiobited sites via \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts or via group policies. Much more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but changing DNS will cause some issues in the network. And other browsers aren't possible on the computers it will be installed.

Comment: well then u have to replace the sources, like i outlines here and like you agree in comments to @YardenST answer.

Only you need to put there not file name but file content. You need to read file in memory and then place its content into body.

but maybe even better would be replacing HTML not body.

there are two reasons for that.

1: HTML/HEAD may already contain some data like JavaScripts or CSSes. Better to remove all data than part. 2: HEAD part specifies the encoding of BODY part. In-memory chars representatino should be consistently declared in header. So you better replace older value